# Creative SDK Image Editor UI in Android project

Tags: java, android, maven, adobecreativesdk

Hi I am trying to integrate Creative sdk into my android application and i have followed this  [click here](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html)

My build.gradle(project) is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files


        /* 1) Add the Gradle Retrolambda Plugin */
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        /* 2) Add mavenCentral */
        mavenCentral()

        /* 3) Add the Creative SDK Maven repo URL */
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and build.gradle(app level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tricurve.com.imgdemoapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        dexOptions {
            jumboMode true
        }
    }

    /* 2) Compile for Java 1.8 or greater */
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    /* 3) Exclude duplicate licenses */
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    /* 4) Add the CSDK framework dependencies (Make sure these version numbers are correct) */
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1186'
}
```

Up to here this works fine but when i try add Image Editor UI [click here](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html)

gradle build getting error [image: like this]
Please some one help me  and they have provide 2 different maven url

```
 maven {
        url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
```

and

```
maven {
        url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public'
    }
```

How to use this please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Both maven URLs are required. One is for the Creative SDK, and one is for Localytics.

In your `build.gradle` (project) file, your `allprojects` block will look like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()    
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
        }

        maven {
            url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public'
        }

    }
}
```

See the `image-editor-ui` directory of the [Creative SDK android-getting-started-samples repo](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples) for a complete sample.

Sample Gradle files and be found [here](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui/code/build.gradle) and [here](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui/code/app/build.gradle).